# Parsing json blob field in Swift

Tags: json, swift, blob

I am reading JSON from a web service in swift which is in the following format

```
[{
   "id":1,
   "shopName":"test",
   "shopBranch":"main",
   "shopAddress":"usa",
   "shopNumber":"5555555",
   "logo":[-1,-40,-1,-32],
   "shopPath":"test"
},
{
   "id":2,
   "shopName":"test",
   "shopBranch":"main",
   "shopAddress":"usa",
   "shopNumber":"66666666",
   "logo":[-1,-50,-2,-2],
   "shopPath":"test"
}]
```

I have managed to read all the strings easily but when it comes to the logo part I am not sure what should I do about it, this is a blob field in a mySQL database which represent an image that I want to retrieve in my swift UI, here is my code for doing that but i keep getting errors and not able to figure the right way to do it:

```
struct Brand: Decodable {
    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id = "id"
        case name = "shopName"
        case branch = "shopBranch"
        case address = "shopAddress"
        case phone = "shopNumber"
        case logo = "logo"
        case path = "shopPath"
    }
    let id: Int
    let name: String
    let branch: String
    let address: String
    let phone: String
    let logo: [String]
    let path: String
}
func getBrandsJson() {
    let url = URL(string: "http://10.211.55.4:8080/exam/Test")
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
        guard let data = data, error == nil else {
            print(error!);
            return
        }
        print(response.debugDescription)
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        let classes = try! decoder.decode([Brand].self, from: data)
        for myClasses in classes {
            print(myClasses.branch)
            if let imageData:Data = myClasses.logo.data(using:String.Encoding.utf8){
                let image = UIImage(data:imageData,scale:1.0)
                var imageView  : UIImageView!
            }
        }
    }).resume()
}
```

Can someone explain how to do that the right way I have searched a lot but no luck

Comment: `let logo: [String]` => `let logo: [Int]`. But that could have been good because I guess that `let classes = try! decoder.decode([Brand].self, from: data)` is creating a crash with an error message in console, to give it to us, and the answer should be in it too. Indeed, error messages are important. If you don't understand them, at least give it to us.

Comment: @vadian well you are correct the logo value is not a string as it is an array of numbers like: "logo":[-1,-40,-1,-32] so i have changed let logo: [String] to let logo: [Int] and then I have changed to this let imageData = Data(myClasses.logo.utf8) but now it says Value of type '[Int]' has no member 'utf8'

Comment: @Larme I have added the compiler error below

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you should better tell the server side engineers of the web service, that using array of numbers is not efficient to return a binary data in JSON and that they should use Base-64 or something like that.

---

If they are stubborn enough to ignore your suggestion, you should better decode it as `Data` in your custom decoding initializer.

```
struct Brand: Decodable {
    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id = "id"
        case name = "shopName"
        case branch = "shopBranch"
        case address = "shopAddress"
        case phone = "shopNumber"
        case logo = "logo"
        case path = "shopPath"
    }
    let id: Int
    let name: String
    let branch: String
    let address: String
    let phone: String
    let logo: Data
    let path: String

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        self.id = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: CodingKeys.id)
        self.name = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: CodingKeys.name)
        self.branch = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: CodingKeys.branch)
        self.address = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: CodingKeys.address)
        self.phone = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: CodingKeys.phone)
        self.path = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: CodingKeys.path)
        //Decode the JSON array of numbers as `[Int8]`
        let bytes = try container.decode([Int8].self, forKey: CodingKeys.logo)
        //Convert the result into `Data`
        self.logo = Data(bytes: bytes.lazy.map{UInt8(bitPattern: $0)})
    }
}
```

And you can write the data decoding part of your `getBrandsJson()` as:

```
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        do {
            //You should never use `try!` when working with data returned by server
            //Generally, you should not ignore errors or invalid inputs silently
            let brands = try decoder.decode([Brand].self, from: data)
            for brand in brands {
                print(brand)
                //Use brand.logo, which is a `Data`
                if let image = UIImage(data: brand.logo, scale: 1.0) {
                    print(image)
                    //...
                } else {
                    print("invalid binary data as an image")
                }
            }
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
```

I wrote some lines to decode array of numbers as `Data` by guess. So if you find my code not working with your actual `data`, please tell me with enough description and some examples of actual data. (At least, you need to show me a first few hundreds of the elements in the actual `"logo"` array.)

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
let logo: [String]
```

with

```
let logo: [Int]
```

to get errors use

```
do {
     let classes = try JSONDecoder().decode([Brand].self, from: data)
}
catch {
  print(error)
}
```

Comment: I have tried that but when I use [Int] the following line will not compile: if let imageData:Data = myClasses.logo.data(using:String.Encoding.utf8){ because Value of type '[Int]' has no member 'data'

Comment: logo is an array of ints , you can't transfer it to image data

Comment: is there any way to retrieve it I can change the data field in the database